# How to map custom DRF api view to multiple urls?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an API view like this:

```
class FollowersView(ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowerSerializer
    queryset = Follower.objects.all()
```

How can I make it work with different URLs with each action - list and retrieve?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('followers/', FollowersView.as_view(), name='followers'),    #all requests are captured here
    path('followers/<int:id>/', FollowersView.as_view(), name='followers-detail'),
]
```

By now each request is catched by list action.

Comment: Currently both paths have the same view function. They should be different.

Comment: @Abhyudai but this is exactly what I am asking about - how to make different urls for 1 api view with different methods (from multiple built-in api view classes)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$` sign to the end of url, because otherwise both `followers/` and `followers/123/` matches the `list` url.:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('followers/$', FollowersView.as_view(), name='followers'),
    path('followers/<int:id>/', FollowersView.as_view(), name='followers-detail'), 
]
```

Or you can have it in single url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^followers(?:/(?P<pk>[0-9]+))?/$',
        FollowersView.as_view(),
        name='followers'),
]
```

Or you can try stich them:

```
urlpatterns = [       
    path('followers/<int:id>/', FollowersView.as_view(), name='followers-detail'), 
    path('followers/', FollowersView.as_view(), name='followers'),
]
```

Comment: no, $ is deprecated from Django 2.0 you can't use it with `path` method.

Comment: @Chiefir I've proposed a solution to switch the urls.